# How do I read unicode characters from SQL server using SQLAPI++?

Tags: c++, sql, unicode, sqlapi++

I'm using SQLAPI++ to build a backend application which needs to access a database (SQL Server 2014). When I try to read a string (nvarchar(50)) from a result set that contains non-ascii characters (specifically persian characters), the `cmd.Field("MyField").asString().GetxxxChars()` methods all return question marks (?) instead of those characters.
What should I do?

I have also tried `asBytes()` and `asLongChar()` and got the same results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I found the problem!

I was linking with sqlapis.lib. I checked [this link](https://www.sqlapi.com/ApiDoc/build-app/) and found out that I should use sqlapi**u**s.lib instead for **u**nicode support. I also needed to define SA_UNICODE.

It is now working fine.